# Different behaviour local and online

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, menu, responsive, dreamweaver

I am really struggling. I am building a new website on https://bike-activities.ch/test/ with Adobe Dreamweaver.
In the Desktop version of the site, I want to have a drop-down menu (on the tablet and the mobile version a Hamburger menu, which works - almost).
If I hover over the dorpdown menu in the online version, text stays white and the menu appears, the background immediately disappears again (see link above). If I look at the exact same site in the Dreamweaver live preview it works - hover changes the font to green, the drop-down work - background color stays black with 0.8 opacity.
Any idea what I am missing?Thank you
Roger

The HTML structure looks like that:
This is the html menu structure:

```
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="kalender.html" >Kalender</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" >Für Kids <i class= "fas fa-angle-down"></i></a>
                    <ul class = "submenu">
                        <li><a href="minami-biken.html">Mittwoch-Nachmittags-Biken</a></li>
                        <li><a href="sicher-auf-dem-schulweg.html">Sicher auf dem Schulweg</a></li>
                        <li><a href="aktive-party.html">Aktive Kinderparty</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#" >Für Ladies <i class= "fas fa-angle-down"></i></a>
                    <ul class = "submenu">
                        <li><a href="ladybike-treff.html">Lady-Bike Treff</a></li>
                        <li><a href="bikekurse.html">Bikekurse</a></li>
                        <li><a href="einsteiger-refresher.html">Velo: Einsteiger/Refresher</a></li>
                        <li><a href="private-coaching.html">Private Coaching</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#" >Für Alle <i class= "fas fa-angle-down"></i></a>
                    <ul class = "submenu">
                        <li><a href="einsteiger-refresher.html">Velo: Einsteiger/Refresher</a></li>
                        <li><a href="private-coaching.html">Private Coaching</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#" >Für Schulen <i class= "fas fa-angle-down"></i></a>
                    <ul class = "submenu">
                        <li><a href="geschicklichkeits-parcours.html">Geschicklichkeits-Parcours</a></li>
                        <li><a href="schul-projekte.html">Unterstützung bei Projekten</a></li>
                        <li><a href="sicher-auf-dem-schulweg.html">Sicher auf dem Schulweg</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="https://gallery.bike-activities.ch/Bike-Activities" target="_blank" >Gallerie</a></li>
                <li><a href="gutschein.html" >Gutschein</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

this is the mobile part of the CSS (menu-wrap is a container around the menu):

```
    .menu-wrap nav {
        background-color: transparent;
        padding-top: 10px;
    }
    .menu-wrap a:hover,
    .menu-wrap a:active {
        color: rgb(151, 191, 13);
        background-color: transparent;
    }
    /* define the layout of the lists */
    .menu-wrap nav > ul {
        max-height: 600px;
        list-style: none;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        max-width: 1500px;
        text-align: left;
    }
    /* override the background for the drop-down from the mobile menu */
    .menu-wrap nav .submenu {
        text-align: left;
        position: absolute;
        min-width: 250px;
        background-color: rgba(13, 9, 9, 0.8);
        visibility: hidden;
        height: 0px;
        z-index: 1000;
        max-height: none;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    /* layout of the text of the drop-down */
    .menu-wrap nav .submenu li {
        padding: 0 0px;
        display: block;
    }
    .menu-wrap nav li {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        flex: 1;
        font-size: 12pt;
    }
    .menu-wrap nav a {
        display: flex;
    }
    /* show the submenu on hover, focus */
    .menu-wrap nav li:hover .submenu, 
    .menu-wrap nav li:active .submenu, 
    .menu-wrap nav li:focus .submenu {
        visibility: visible;
        height: auto;
        background-color: rgba(13, 9, 9, 0.8);
    }
    .menu-wrap nav li:focus-within .submenu {
        visibility: visible;
        height: auto;
        background-color: rgba(13, 9, 9, 0.8);
    }
```

And this is overridden by the CSS for the desktop:

```
    .menu-wrap nav {
        background-color: transparent;
        padding-top: 10px;
    }
    .menu-wrap a:hover,
    .menu-wrap a:active {
        color: rgb(151, 191, 13);
        background-color: transparent;
    }
    /* define the layout of the lists */
    .menu-wrap nav > ul {
        max-height: 600px;
        list-style: none;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        max-width: 1500px;
        text-align: left;
    }
    /* override the background for the drop-down from the mobile menu */
    .menu-wrap nav .submenu {
        text-align: left;
        position: absolute;
        min-width: 250px;
        background-color: rgba(13, 9, 9, 0.8);
        visibility: hidden;
        height: 0px;
        z-index: 1000;
        max-height: none;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    /* layout of the text of the drop-down */
    .menu-wrap nav .submenu li {
        padding: 0 0px;
        display: block;
    }
    .menu-wrap nav li {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        flex: 1;
        font-size: 12pt;
    }
    .menu-wrap nav a {
        display: flex;
    }
    /* show the submenu on hover, focus */
    .menu-wrap nav li:hover .submenu, 
    .menu-wrap nav li:active .submenu, 
    .menu-wrap nav li:focus .submenu {
        visibility: visible;
        height: auto;
        background-color: rgba(13, 9, 9, 0.8);
    }
    .menu-wrap nav li:focus-within .submenu {
        visibility: visible;
        height: auto;
        background-color: rgba(13, 9, 9, 0.8);
    }
    /* </menu definition> */
```

Comment: you need to add some code in order for us to help you

Comment: I see no mobile @media declaration in the css file and you cannot rely on an editors or browsers preview for mobile devices. It is doable in dev tools, but don't rely on it.  Use a proper mobile device for testing. There is no hover event on mobile, a fingers touch will simply trigger the defined hover behaviour, which seems to be ok for this use case. Else you will need to work with touch events. But as far I can see, there is no at media rule for sub 450px width devices there.

Comment: @ptts: Thank you. The challenge I have is with the desktop version, mobile is ok.

Comment: @JorgeGuerreiro done. It is strange. Currently it seems to me that the drop-down works but the hover does not, yet

Comment: What I do not understand: I just realized that it seems to work on Firefox and Brave but not on Edge and Chrome.

Comment: @roger works for me in chrome. That is why I thought it might now be working on mobile.

Comment: @ptts Hover over as well? The font should turn green